Proper way to handle billing in an API Service using Laravel Cashier-Paddle
I have a laravel 11 API service and I will like to implement billing, I have the entire business logic in the API service but i seem to be having a challenge about how to implement billing/subscription in my API service, the original idea was to have a /subscriptions endpoint on the API that would return list of subscriptions and a link to make payment but cashier-paddle seems to be functioning differently, I.e: I cant seem to get/be able return the subscriptions/payment link for my products/plans.
The API is to show the plans and their payment link or link to cancel subscription if they are only on said plan.
Thank you in advance.
